# Headset is recognized but does not work Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, laptop, microphone

[the indicator moves, but it is not responding to the audio, it is only at the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YJEA.png)

---

Tried hdajackretask and changed models in alsa-base.conf but nothing worked.

my laptop is an acer nitro 5 an515
my sound card is realtek acl255